# Unable to unpack values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a dictionary say

```
a = { 'a': 'abc',
'b': 'xyz',
'c': 'yyy'

}
```

and another list of dictionaries say

```
list_dict = [{'id': 5903032523805, 'value': 'aaa'}, {'id': 5903031568925, 'value': 'bbb'}, {'id': 5902976332061, 'value': 'ccc'}]
```

How do I perform

```
for i, j in list_dict, a.values():
    print(i['id'], j)
```

Error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Now i'm aware that a.values returns dict_values[()] as individual items (iterate) as output and also i['id'] returns first dictionary id (1st item in list). But when combined in a for loop , unable to extract it. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268098/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-2)

Comment: For an explanation of what's going on: What you've done here is create a tuple with the following structure: (dict, List[dict]), so it will unload the first element (the dict) but it expects 3 values instead of two since that's how many keys are in your dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using zip.

```py
for (i, j) in zip(list_dict, a.values()):
     print(i['id'], j)
```

Output:

```
5903032523805 abc
5903031568925 xyz
5902976332061 yyy
```

Comment: Thank you @Liju. I had studied about zip(zipping two datastructure values into one single tuple like ((,), (,)) but did not remember to use it here.